# Wait until a symbol provider is available

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am writing a Go adapter extension for the [Test Explorer extension](https://github.com/hbenl/vscode-test-explorer) for Visual Studio Code. My extension uses language services from Microsoft's [Go extension](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-go):

```js
const symbols = await vscode.commands.executeCommand('vscode.executeDocumentSymbolProvider', uri)
```

However, I have an issue. When I specify `extensionDependencies` and `activationEvents` correctly (in package.json), symbols don't initially load (the command returns `undefined`). If I set `activationEvents` to `*` or if I delay for long enough in my activate handler, symbols load. I thought about retrying until the command returns something, but "this file has no symbols" and "there is no symbol provider for this type of document" both return `undefined`.

Is there a way to delay until a symbol provider has been defined for a specific file extension/language? Waiting for the Go extension to be activated is not enough. I would use `GoDocumentSymbolProvider` directly, but the extension doesn't export anything.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like it will be possible to add a delay time before your extension is activated.  See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/98083 (Add support to eventually activate an extension on startup).  And https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/98990 (Delayed startup activation events).

Will be in v1.46. From v1.46 release notes [`onStartupFinished` activation event](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_46.md#onstartupfinished-activation-event):

> We now have a new activation event, similar to the already existing *
>   activation event. The new `onStartupFinished` activation event should
>   be used when an extension wishes to be activated sometime soon after
>   VS Code startup, but not as part of the startup.

However, it is just a hard-coded delay, not based on other events but may still help your situation.

> There is a new activation event which looks like e.g. `onStartup:1000`
>   or `onStartup:5000`. This means that the extension wants to be
>   activated 1000ms or 5000ms after startup. This is very similar to *
>   activation, but the extension indicates that it can wait a bit.